# cannot use min formula with index/match , to bring the best price of same brands

Tags: excel, vlookup, min, index-match

[image: sample]

I want to enter a Brand manually and want to see the lowest price among the offers

How can I do it without re-arranging the data, without changing columns etc.?

I tried to the with index/match but cannot incorporate the min. It is bringing the first hit, ignoring the other offers whith same brand.

Comment: Have you tried using `MINIFS`? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHVXG.png